# upgrading TFS from 2013 to 2015, would TFS Build continue to work for BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, tfsbuild, biztalk-2013r2

We are using BizTalk 2013 R2, currently under TFS 2013. We using TFS build feature and we are thinking to upgrade TFS to 2015.

Not sure if the BizTalk build will continue to work?

Comment: It should still work, we migrated a few months ago and didn't have too much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading TFS from TFS2013 to TFS2015, for the build: there will be a new build system-vNext build. To the old build system-XAML build, there are almost the same between TFS2013 and TFS2015. So if you are **still using XAML build**, it will continue work

Answer (score 0):

Patrick is correct but may confuse someone.

TFS 2015 adds a completely new build infrastructure, called vNext, which I suggest to look at. It can simplify and help a lot.

TFS 2015 works fine with existing builds: not only they should work without changes, also the infrastructure. You can keep your existing 2013 Controllers and Agents, no need to upgrade them.